# Abrindo ( ) automaticamente no vscode igual no pycharm

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Usando o pycharm quando chama uma função ou um método, os ( ) são abertos automaticamente, teria alguma configuração que faz isso no vscode?

Answer (score 0):

Vá em configurações digite esse comando: Complete Function Calls na barra de pesquisa e selecione a opção Complete Function Calls, tanto para javascript como typescript.

[image: Complete Function Calls]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).